# Does db:schema:load delete existing tables and create new ? if yes, how to not make it delete existing tables and data ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I already have tables in my db on production server which I created by running

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

Now I have created some more migrations and is looking to run db:schema:load again but will it drop existing tables since I am on production and I do have data in them ? I can see in my db/schema.rb file, I have

create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|

deleting and creating tables looks to be extremely risky, is there any other way to do this ? I am using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, loading the schema will remove all data. You can simply set `force` to `false` inside your schema, but then postgresql will give you an error because the table already exists and the schema will not be loaded.

The question is really what you are trying to achieve. If you have some migrations, why not just run them in the production environment?

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

If there is really no way around this and your new schema still supports data from the old one, I suggest you dump the data, load the schema, and then load the data again. For this, you can use [yaml_db](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db).

Comment: Thanks @Charles, well I had looked into schema.db file and it said that you if are creating the same tables agian, on a different server, then you are better of using schema.db instead of db:migrate though I certainly can't afford to lose data. So db:migrate will only create those tables which are not created ? how to run ONLY a specific migration just to be on safer side ?

Comment: Migrations are like a storyline for your database structure to reflect different states of your database at different states of development. They are not there to populate your database. If you move to another server, you should just load the schema and then transfer data from your old database to your new one using something like yaml_db.

Comment: Right Charles, I meant, say I created 2 migrations on my local server, now I want to replicate that on the server, I can put my migration file on servers and run db:migrate or run db:schema:load since I read that db:migrate can break things, which method will you prefer ?

Comment: Migrations will not touch your data, loading the schema will. It seems like you want to keep your production data, so you should use migrations.